# AWS Step Function: check for null

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Step Function is defined like that:

```
{
  "StartAt": "Decision_Maker",
  "States": {
    "Decision_Maker":{
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.body.MyData",
          "StringEquals": "null", //that doesn't work :(
          "Next": "Run_Task1"
        }],
        "Default": "Run_Task2"
    },
    "Run_Task1": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "url_1",
      "Next": "Run_Task2"
    },
    "Run_Task2": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "url_2",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Basically it's a choice between 2 tasks.
Input data is like this:

```
{
    "body": {
        "prop1": "value1",
        "myData": {
            "otherProp": "value"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes there's no myData in JSON. So input may come like this:

```
{
    "body": {
        "prop1": "value1",
        "myData": null
    }
}
```

How do I check whether or not myData is null?

Comment: your ask will not work as stringequals look for string only..There are 2 things you can do. 1. Before choice , preprocess your input with lamda 2. using the exception handling for checking keynotfounderror

Comment: https://github.com/awslabs/statelint/issues/7

Comment: See my answer for the current recommendation. Amazon States Language now supports null checks in Choice states

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**As of August 2020, Amazon States Language now has an `isNull` and `isPresent` Choice Rule.** Using these you can natively check for `null` or the existence of a key in the state input inside a Choice state.

Example:

```
{ "Variable": "$.possiblyNullValue", "IsNull": true }
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html#amazon-states-language-choice-state-rules

Comment: This is the most useful answer, the accepted answer is out of date.

Answer (score 3):

The order matters. Set the "`IsPresent": false` first, then the `"IsNull": true`, finally the scalar comparison last.

```json
    "Check MyValue": {
      "Comment": "Check MyValue",
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Default": "ContinueWithMyValue",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Or": [
            {
              "Variable": "$.MyValue",
              "IsPresent": false
            },
            {
              "Variable": "$.MyValue",
              "IsNull": true
            },
            {
              "Variable": "$.MyValue",
              "BooleanEquals": false
            }
          ],
          "Next": "HaltProcessing"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.MyValue",
          "BooleanEquals": true,
          "Next": "ContinueWithMyValue"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Is of type null]

You have to use the Not is of type null

Answer (score -1):

As per my experience, Choice Type can't deal nulls. Best way could be pre-processing your input using a lambda in the very first state and return the event formatting it as "null". Below code snippet might help.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
if event['body']['MyData']:
    return event
else:
    event['body']['MyData']="null"
    return event
```

**Note:** This also handles empty string.

Comment: This is no longer accurate. See the other answer by adamwong for more useful and up to date information.